# Number of planes with maximum atoms

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

> Number of planes in $\text{SiH$_2$FCl}$ which contain maximum atoms but all must be different?

I am interested in the above problem. I predicted the answer to $10$ which indeed is $5\choose 3$ because maximum number of points in a plane will be $3$ since the structure is tetrahedral. But the book writes an answer $7$ to the above problem!! Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I predicted the answer to 10 which indeed is $5\choose 3$ because maximum number of points in a plane will be 3 since the structure is tetrahedral.

Yes, 10 is the number of sets with three atoms, and each set defines a unique plane.

> But the book writes an answer 7 to the above problem

3 of those (HHSi, HHF, HHCl) don’t count, so 7.